# How can I display the spinning NSProgressIndicator in a different color?

Tags: cocoa

I am using a "spinner" NSProgressIndicator in my cocoa app:

[image: spinner image]

I would like to display it in a different color so that it will show up well on a dark background:

[image: inverted spinner image]

How would I go about doing this? My last resort would be to write my own custom NSView subclass that renders a custom animation, but I'm not even sure where to start on that front. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I actually have implemented clones of the spinning NSProgressIndicator that might suit your needs.  They can be drawn at any size and in any color.  One is a subclass of NSView, which can be used on OS X 10.4, and the other is a subclass of CALayer, which can be used in a CoreAnimation-based project.  The code is on github (both the [NSView-based](https://github.com/kelan/yrk-spinning-progress-indicator) version and the [CoreAnimation-based](https://github.com/kelan/yrk-spinning-progress-indicator-layer) version), and there is a [post with some screenshots](http://yeahrightkeller.com/2009/yrkspinningprogressindicators/) on my blog.

Comment: Nice work! And here I thought this question was long dead. Thank you for the links and the code.

Comment: FYI for others, this is pre-ARC code and is frustrating to update.  I'm sure it worked at some point, but I gave up after losing a few hours to this.

Comment: It's working for me in a Yosemite project by adding the spinning progress indicator layer to a container layer of the same size. I set a constraint to position the container layer in the centre of the parent layer, and offset the container layer in x and y by half its width and height so the spinner appears positioned correctly in the container layer. NB: Don't set any autoresizing mask on the container layer. Also updated the original to an ARC version (and sent a pull request to @Kelan).

Answer (score 26):

This is what I've done:

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    ...

    CIFilter *lighten = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [lighten setDefaults];
    [lighten setValue:@1 forKey:@"inputBrightness"];
    [self.indicator setContentFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:lighten, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me for setting the indicator to we white. Do you have any sources for documentation on all available keys and value ranges?

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if this would work correctly with NSProgressIndicator, but you might try using a Core Image filter to invert the display of the progress indicator view.  You would have to make the view layer backed, and then add a `CIFilter` to its layer's filters.  You may be able to do this all in the effects inspector in Interface Builder, otherwise you could also just do it in code.

Comment: Fantastic! I added "Color Controls" as a "Content Filter" and set saturation, brightness and contrast to 1 in Interface Builder for a nice white progress indicator.

Comment: However, adding a color controls filter may have other side effects. E.g. my slide animation no longer works with that set. Removing the filter makes everything working again.

Comment: @nschum How did you do that in Interface Builder?

Comment: I discovered side effects of the `Color Controls` solution too. I used this within a NSCell and the whole Window started to flicker when I reloaded a NSTableView. Took me two weeks to find this coherence (:

Comment: I spent a whole day tracking down weird side effects of using a CIFilter in the xib. Don't do it!

Answer (score 5):

While I'm sure that Kelan's code worked a while ago, it's difficult to update.  I ended up going with [ITProgressIndicator](https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITProgressIndicator), and it took about 2 minutes to get working using Xcode 6 (Beta 1) and Yosemite (Beta 2).

Answer (score 5):

For a more fine grained solution, you can use a polynomial color approach using the following Category. Please note that for simplicity I use only the x component of the vectors. For more accurate color matching please see reference at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMatrix

```
@import QuartzCore;
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSProgressIndicator (Colors)

- (void)setCustomColor:(NSColor *)aColor;

@end

@implementation NSProgressIndicator (Colors)

- (void)setCustomColor:(NSColor *)aColor {
    CIFilter *colorPoly = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPolynomial"];
    [colorPoly setDefaults];

    CIVector *redVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:aColor.redComponent Y:0 Z:0 W:0];
    CIVector *greenVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:aColor.greenComponent Y:0 Z:0 W:0];
    CIVector *blueVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:aColor.blueComponent Y:0 Z:0 W:0];
    [colorPoly setValue:redVector forKey:@"inputRedCoefficients"];
    [colorPoly setValue:greenVector forKey:@"inputGreenCoefficients"];
    [colorPoly setValue:blueVector forKey:@"inputBlueCoefficients"];
    [self setContentFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:colorPoly, nil]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you’re targeting Mojave or later, you can just set the spinner’s appearance to dark aqua. This will always give you a white spinner, regardless of the user’s system appearance.

```
spinner.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let brightness = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
    brightness.setDefaults()
    brightness.setValue(1, forKey: "inputBrightness")
    self.spinner.contentFilters = [brightness]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some third party HUD-style control frameworks that include the bar style NSProgressIndicator, but unfortunately I don't remember ever seeing the spinner. If you can't find a way to get it to do what you want, [this page](http://www.ajaxload.info/) can generate an animated gif that might be helpful for making your own.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Solution**

```
guard let lighten = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls") else { return }
lighten.setDefaults()
lighten.setValue(1, forKey: "inputBrightness")
contentFilters = [lighten]
```