# Tinting a grayscale NSImage (or CIImage)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image

I have a grayscale image which I want to use for drawing Cocoa controls. The image has various levels of gray. Where it is darkest, I want it to draw a specified tint color darkest. I want it to be transparent where the source image is white.

Basically, I want to reproduce the behavior of tintColor seen in UINavigationBar on the iPhone.

So far, I have explored several options:

- Draw the tint color over the grayscale image using SourceOver composition
  -> This requires a non-opaque tint color
  -> The result comes out much darker than desired
- Use a CIMultiplyCompositing CIFilter to tint the image
  -> I can't [CIImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] to draw only part of the image. The same works fine with NSImage
  -> I get occasional crashes which I cannot make sense of
- Transform the grayscale image into a mask. I.e. Black should be opaque. White should be transparent. Gray should have intermediate alpha values.
  -> This would seem to be the best solution
  -> Try as I might, I cannot achieve this.

Comment: I have resolved to doing the tinting and cropping in two successive steps. CIMultiplyCompositing works fine as long as I draw the whole image. I draw to an NSImage, which in turn I draw partially to a smaller image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
- (NSImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(NSColor *)tint 
{
    if (tint != nil) {
        NSSize size = [self size];
        NSRect bounds = { NSZeroPoint, size };
        NSImage *tintedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];

        [tintedImage lockFocus];

        CIFilter *colorGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIConstantColorGenerator"];
        CIColor *color = [[[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:tint] autorelease];

        [colorGenerator setValue:color forKey:@"inputColor"];

        CIFilter *monochromeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
        CIImage *baseImage = [CIImage imageWithData:[self TIFFRepresentation]];

        [monochromeFilter setValue:baseImage forKey:@"inputImage"];     
        [monochromeFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.75 blue:0.75] forKey:@"inputColor"];
        [monochromeFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];

        CIFilter *compositingFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMultiplyCompositing"];

        [compositingFilter setValue:[colorGenerator valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [compositingFilter setValue:[monochromeFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

        CIImage *outputImage = [compositingFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

        [outputImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint
                        fromRect:bounds
                       operation:NSCompositeCopy
                        fraction:1.0];

        [tintedImage unlockFocus];  

        return [tintedImage autorelease];
    }
    else {
        return [[self copy] autorelease];
    }
}

- (NSImage*)imageCroppedToRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSPoint point = { -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y };
    NSImage *croppedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rect.size];

    [croppedImage lockFocus];
    {
        [self compositeToPoint:point operation:NSCompositeCopy];
    }
    [croppedImage unlockFocus];

    return [croppedImage autorelease];
}
```

Comment: It really takes unnecessary time for n00bs like me to figure out how to use this code: 1- Link QuartzCore 2- import it 3- Add a NSImage category with this awesome code inside.

Comment: Yeah, I concur..  This code rocks… but not implicitly saying _it's a category_ is gonna leave a lot of people dumbfounded.  for all you dumbies.. If you don't know what a category is.. save this code, go figure out what a category is, then come back and use it.  ∀Ⓛ∃✖

Comment: although i understand the code i can't seem to get any result out of it. i feed it a tiff image with an all-black icon and transparent background and try to tint it with white or black. but it stays black.

Comment: The above code will transform gray pixels to tinted pixels of an equally dark shade of the tint color. If your source image is black, the result will also be black.

Comment: I have no published a slightly updated version of the above code to GitHub: https://github.com/gloubibou/NSImage-HHTint

Comment: ah, i see now. thanks for sharing. i can't seem to figure out how to implement this with a white base image, though. i guess i'd have to tweak the `CIMultiplyCompositing` filter or replace it with another one...

Comment: `NSImage lockFocus` is deprecated as of macOS 13.0.

Answer (score 44):

The above solution didn't work for me. But this much easier solution works great for me

```
- (NSImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(NSColor *)tint
{
    NSImage *image = [self copy];
    if (tint) {
        [image lockFocus];
        [tint set];
        NSRect imageRect = {NSZeroPoint, [image size]};
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, NSCompositeSourceIn);
        [image unlockFocus];
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this proves useful to someone in the future:  If you're having problems getting this code to work, set the copied image to NOT be a template ie before returning image, [image setTemplate:NO].  Somewhat counter-intuitively, if the image is set as a template, it will completely ignore the code coloring the image, even though the debugger preview will show you that the image is colored correctly.

I personally ran into this problem because I'm sharing an asset catalog with an iOS project where the image sets are all set to be templates.

Comment: Everything was working, but I had to turn off Template Image in the asset catalog for this to work. Very important point, thanks!

Comment: This works but it makes my image blurry. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: `NSImage lockFocus` is deprecated as of macOS 13.0.

Comment: @HangarRash use the imagewithsize:flipped:drawingHandler: and you will get the same result

Answer (score 15):

A Swift implementation of bluebamboo's answer:

```
func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, tint: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    guard let tinted = image.copy() as? NSImage else { return image }
    tinted.lockFocus()
    tint.set()

    let imageRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, .sourceAtop)

    tinted.unlockFocus()
    return tinted
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the Swift translation. I did it on the fly so I translated the first answer. Next time i can just scroll down here and get it in Swift. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm for me.

Just a note quick note (at least on macOS) it does not work if the image that you use is set to render as "Template", choose render as "Default".

Comment: For me I had to use `imageRect.fill(using:)`

Comment: You need to use `.sourceIn` for it to tint properly, especially if you're trying to replace the original color with a lighter tint

Comment: `NSImage lockFocus` is deprecated as of macOS 13.0.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to tint an image with a tint color that had alpha without seeing the original colors of the image show through. Here's how you can do that:

```
extension NSImage {
    func tinting(with tintColor: NSColor) -> NSImage {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) else { return self }

        return NSImage(size: size, flipped: false) { bounds in
            guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return false }

            tintColor.set()
            context.clip(to: bounds, mask: cgImage)
            context.fill(bounds)

            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CIMultiplyCompositing filter is definitely the way to do this. If it's crashing, can you post a stack trace? I use CIFilters heavily and don't have crashing issues.

```
//assume inputImage is the greyscale CIImage you want to tint

CIImage* outputImage = nil;

//create some green
CIFilter* greenGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIConstantColorGenerator"];
CIColor* green = [CIColor colorWithRed:0.30 green:0.596 blue:0.172];
[greenGenerator setValue:green forKey:@"inputColor"];
CIImage* greenImage = [greenGenerator valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

//apply a multiply filter
CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMultiplyCompositing"];
[filter setValue:greenImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

[outputImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSRectFromCGRect([outputImage extent]) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
```

Comment: Do you really need to use the "CIConstantColorGenerator"? Why not CIImage *greenImage = [CIImage imageWithColor: green]; ?

Comment: Yes, you could. That method was only introduced in 10.5 and back in 2009 when I wrote this answer Tiger was still in common use.

Comment: what is the purpose of the last line of the code? isn't the outputImage already produced on the line before that?

Comment: It's just an example of how to draw the `CIImage`, it's not actually necessary for obtaining the image itself. As you point out, you already have the actual image from the code on the previous line.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version in form of Extension :

```
extension NSImage {
    func tintedImageWithColor(color:NSColor) -> NSImage {
        let size        = self.size
        let imageBounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        let copiedImage = self.copy() as! NSImage

        copiedImage.lockFocus()
        color.set()
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageBounds, .CompositeSourceIn)
        copiedImage.unlockFocus()

        return copiedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Following the new Swift API guidelines, you could change the definition to: `func tinted(color: NSColor) -> NSImage`

Comment: thanks, I'll  check if code compiles under swift 3.0 and update the answer.

Comment: A note that `lockFocus` is deprecated as of macOS 13.0.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5** version that also handles the alpha component of the tint color.

I use this to support dark mode with multiple icon states by converting template icons to different colors and transparency levels. For example, you could pass `NSColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)` to get a dimmed version of an icon for light mode, and `NSColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)` to get a dimmed version for dark mode.

```
func tintedImage(_ image: NSImage, color: NSColor) -> NSImage {
    let newImage = NSImage(size: image.size)
    newImage.lockFocus()

    // Draw with specified transparency
    let imageRect = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
    image.draw(in: imageRect, from: imageRect, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: color.alphaComponent)

    // Tint with color
    color.withAlphaComponent(1).set()
    imageRect.fill(using: .sourceAtop)

    newImage.unlockFocus()
    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a rewrite from deprecated `- (void)lockFocus;` to `imageWithSize:flipped:drawingHandler:`

```
@interface NSImage(Additions)
- (NSImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(NSColor *)tint;
@end

@implementation NSImage(Additions)

- (NSImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(NSColor *)tint
{
    NSImage *copy = [self copy]; // we need to break block retain cycle
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageWithSize:copy.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
        [tint set];
        NSRect imageRect = {NSZeroPoint, [copy size]};
        [copy drawInRect:imageRect];
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, NSCompositingOperationSourceIn);
        return YES;
    }];
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more fine grained, you can use a polynomial color approach, using the approach that I suggested in the following: [How can I display the spinning NSProgressIndicator in a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456445/how-can-i-display-the-spinning-nsprogressindicator-in-a-different-color/32396595#32396595)

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 13.0, `lockFocus` is deprecated.
I made it work like this using symbol config:

```
let config = NSImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.systemTeal, .systemGray])
let nuImage = image.withSymbolConfiguration(config)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519891-lockfocus) for the deprecated `lockFocus` shows what should be used instead.