# NSImage : Change brightness

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, brightness

I want to change the *"brightness"* of an `NSImage`.

I've searched a bit around but I found nothing really helpful...

So, what is the easiest, Cocoa-friendly way to do that?

Comment: the silly way to do it would be to increase the rgb values of each pixel (not going over 255) but I bet there are Quartz filters to do this.

Comment: tint the image with more white balance?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413135/tinting-a-grayscale-nsimage-or-ciimage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with **Core Image Filters**. But You need to use `CIImage` not `NSImage` so You will need to convert it. Here is [CIFilter Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) with all filters. Take a look at "**CIColorControls**" it will let You achieve what You want.

> **CIColorControls**
>
> Adjusts saturation, brightness, and contrast values.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *inputImage* (A CIImage class whose display name is Image).
>
> *inputSaturation* (An NSNumber class whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Saturation.
>   Default value: 1.00 Minimum: 0.00 Maximum: 2.00 Slider minimum: 0.00 Slider maximum: 2.00 Identity: 1.00)
>
> *inputBrightness* (An NSNumber class whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Brightness.
>   Default value: 0.00 Minimum: -1.00 Maximum: 1.00 Slider minimum: -1.00 Slider maximum: 1.00 Identity: 0.00)
>
> *inputContrast* (An NSNumber class whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeScalar and whose display name is Contrast.
>   Default value: 1.00 Minimum: 0.00 Maximum: 4.00 Slider minimum: 0.00 Slider maximum: 4.00 Identity: 1.00)

Comment: Justin - did they change the documentation? What you have listed above is different from what's in the documents, IE it doesn't list the minimum and maximum values. Or did you get that from somewhere else?

Comment: @CoDEFRo I get it from Apple developer library from link to reference. They have changed documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use coreImage. Take a look at Core Image Fun House application [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009216-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).