# White NSProgressIndicator

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting, nsprogressindicator

How can I get a white `NSProgressIndicator`?

I've seen some other solutions on SO and various other blogs, but those all seem a bit dated and don't appear to be ARC-compatible.

Comment: try to set the tint color.

Comment: Tried it, nothing happens.

Comment: check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456445/how-can-i-display-the-spinning-nsprogressindicator-in-a-different-color

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but have you looked at the -setControlTint: method?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it. Nothing happens basically, other answers to similar questions on SO basically say this doesn't work for that.

Comment: Doesn't work: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/53719-setting-color-of-progress-indicator.html